# Searching Gmail for messages without a particular label

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-search

I need to find, in Gmail, a list of all my unread messages — which I can get via `is:unread` or `label:unread` or `l:^u` — which do **not** have the label "ZDNet."

In other words, my requirement is this:

I have 185 e-mails which are "unread" in my Inbox.
I have 174 "unread" e-mails which are labeled "ZDNet."
I need to find the 11 e-mails in my inbox that are not part of the group of 174.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
is:unread -label:ZDNet
```